# How to resume OSM data loading or load new OSM data to the existing installation without replacing the old data?

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, gis, openstreetmap, osmosis

I am trying to install the Openstreetmap website server on a local machine. I am trying to load the whole Planet OSM data. Due to the power outage, data loading was interrupted after 16 days of on-stop loading operation. I want to resume that loading operation from that interruption point. I am following this tutorial -- "https://github.com/openstreetmap/openstreetmap-website/blob/master/DOCKER.md"

This tutorial for the fresh installation and it assumes that there is no geographic data loaded. But in my case, there is some data that is already loaded. I tried with -- "

```
docker-compose run --rm web osmosis \
    -verbose    \
    --read-pbf district-of-columbia-latest.osm.pbf \
    --log-progress \
    --write-apidb \
        host="db" \
        database="openstreetmap" \
        user="openstreetmap" \
        validateSchemaVersion="no"
```

"
Also with -- "

```
docker-compose run --rm web osmosis \
-verbose \
--read-pbf new-data-file.osm.pbf \
--log-progress \
--write-apidb \
host="db" \
database="openstreetmap" \
user="openstreetmap" \
validateSchemaVersion="no" \
--append
```

"
But none of these attempts came with luck.